# No more SVN console client for Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, apache, console

Am I right thinking that [Tigris.org](http://Tigris.org) have stopped maintaining their SVN binary package for Windows including Apache 2.x compatible package? It isn't listed any more on the [Download](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) page. It's very interesting why does it happened?

What alternatives are there now? Only SlikSVN? Does it have any differences with old Tirgris SVN?

And how to install know SVN with Apache under Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the page on apache.org: [Subversion Binary Packages](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html), the choices you now have are:

- CollabNet,
- SlikSVN
- VisualSVN
- WANdisco

So indeed, it looks like the old releases are no longer part of the official lineup. To be blunt, they were always a bit of an afterthought (or so it seemed), since it could easily take up to a week or two after a new release before a new windows binary was released.

I'd go with SlikSVN.

Answer (score 1):

Have there ever been Windows binaries on the Tigris site (now moved to Apache)? The only place to download them that I know of is [CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/), where they seem to be alive and well.

They are also linked to on the [official binary downloads](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) page.

Comment: There were binaries released by some members of the community, made available on a sub-page of the old tigris pages, but these seems to have disappeared and are apparently no longer maintained.

Comment: @Lasse ah, okay. I'd never seen those.